# Angular - Load and route a compiled microfrontend from npm

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a question that I've been struggling to find an answer to, and I've been wasting a lot of time on futile attempts.

I'm using Angular 15 with a microfrontend architecture, and I need to implement a structure where I can download a compiled microfrontend using npm and visualize it in a development environment where I have the shell. The microfrontend is developed separately as a regular Angular application.

Without going into too much detail about the microfrontend architecture, it follows the classic pattern where, at a certain point, a manifest is read that defines the URL of the microfrontend to be loaded:

```json
{
   "mfe1": "http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js"
}
```

What I would like to achieve is the possibility of making the compiled microfrontend available at the URL mentioned above, which points to the microfrontend compiled code present in the node_modules directory.

I don't have this issue in production because I will replace that URL with the server's URL hosting the compiled microfrontend. However, during development, I would like to be able to load it dynamically from node_modules where the remoteEntry.js resides.

For this project, I need to keep the development of the shell and microfrontends separate, and I can only download the microfrontends in their compiled form.

Is this possible?

Compared to a typical microfrontend architecture, I've attempted to modify the angular.json file to make my MFE1 point not to a folder like projects/mfe1/src/... but rather to the compiled code in node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

@update [Solved]

I found an even better solution, perhaps the definitive one, it is obtained by polarizing the angular.json.

in the "development/assets" section add this line:

```
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "./node_modules/@my-package-whit-compiled-mfe/...", "output": "./assets/mfe/my-mfe-name" }
```

it will looks like this:

```
"development": {
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "optimization": false,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "extractLicenses": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "namedChunks": true,
    "assets": [
        "projects/shell/src/favicon.ico",
        "projects/shell/src/assets",
        { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./node_modules/@my-package-whit-compiled-mfe/...", "output": "./assets/mfe/my-mfe-name" }
               ]
}
```

This will ensure that when the shell is compiled, the compiled microfrontend is copied to the assets folder.

at this point modify the string defined in the manifest to load the microfrontend as follows:

```
{
   "mfe1": "http://localhost:5000/assets/mfe/my-mfe-name/remoteEntry.js"
}
```

Et voilà!